# Android - Youtube 3gp file not found

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-video-player

I'm trying to play a youtube video on my Android app, but I can't reach the 3gp url returned me from Youtube Api.
I tried to open it also in VLC player and QuickTime player, but response is always that the player cannot receive data.
Here is VLC Player log:

> main debug: `rtsp://v5.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmyk7Qe6Z5HyRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp' successfully opened
>   live555 warning: no data received in 10s. Switching to TCP
>   avcodec debug: ffmpeg codec (H263) stopped
>   main debug: removing module "avcodec"
>   main debug: killing decoder fourcc`h263', 0 PES in FIFO
>   avcodec debug: ffmpeg codec (AMR narrow band) stopped
>   main debug: removing module "avcodec"
>   main debug: killing decoder fourcc `samr', 0 PES in FIFO
>   main debug: Program doesn't contain anymore ES
>   live555 debug: RTP subsession 'video/H263-2000'
>   main debug: looking for decoder module: 32 candidates
>   avcodec debug: libavcodec already initialized
>   avcodec debug: trying to use direct rendering
>   avcodec debug: ffmpeg codec (H263) started
>   main debug: using decoder module "avcodec"
>   main debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.758 ms - Total 0.758 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.758 ms)
>   main debug: thread (decoder) created at priority 0 (../../src/input/decoder.c:301)
>   main debug: thread started
>   live555 debug: RTP subsession 'audio/AMR'
>   main debug: looking for decoder module: 32 candidates
>   avcodec debug: libavcodec already initialized
>   avcodec debug: ffmpeg codec (AMR narrow band) started
>   avcodec debug: Using 192000 bytes output buffer
>   main debug: using decoder module "avcodec"
>   main debug: TIMER module_need() : 391.931 ms - Total 391.931 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 391.931 ms)
>   main debug: thread (decoder) created at priority 22 (../../src/input/decoder.c:301)
>   main debug: thread started
>   live555 debug: setup start: 0.000000 stop:28.666000
>   live555 debug: play start: 0.000000 stop:28.666000
>   live555 error: no data received in 10s, aborting
>   main debug: EOF reached
>   main debug: finished input
>   avcodec debug: ffmpeg codec (H263) stopped
>   main debug: removing module "avcodec"
>   main debug: killing decoder fourcc`h263', 0 PES in FIFO
>   avcodec debug: ffmpeg codec (AMR narrow band) stopped
>   main debug: removing module "avcodec"
>   main debug: killing decoder fourcc `samr', 0 PES in FIFO
>   main debug: removing module "live555"
>   main debug: Program doesn't contain anymore ES
>   main debug: thread ended
>   main debug: dead input
>   main debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
>   main debug: nothing to play
>   macosx debug: input has stopped, refreshing interface
>   main debug: TIMER input launching for 'rtsp://v5.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmyk7Qe6Z5HyRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp' : 449.262 ms - Total 449.262 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 449.262 ms)

And this is Android log:

> 05-18 14:51:42.008: D/MediaPlayer(2152): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
>   05-18 14:51:42.258: D/MediaPlayer(2152): getMetadata
>   05-18 14:51:53.823: E/MediaPlayer(2152): error (1, -2147483648)
>   05-18 14:51:53.823: E/MediaPlayer(2152): Error (1,-2147483648)
>   05-18 14:51:53.823: D/VideoView(2152): Error: 1,-2147483648
>   05-18 14:51:54.060: D/AndroidRuntime(2152): Shutting down VM
>   05-18 14:51:54.060: W/dalvikvm(2152): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@418c8408 is not valid; is your activity running?
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:513)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.widget.VideoView$4.onError(VideoView.java:382)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:1553)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   05-18 14:51:54.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

And my VideoActivity class to play the video:

```
    public class VideoActivity extends Activity{

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.video);

            VideoView videoView = new VideoView(this);
            String urlRtsp = "rtsp://v5.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmyk7Qe6Z5HyRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp";
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlRtsp));
            videoView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();
            LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.video_layout);
            main.addView(videoView);        
       }


    }
```

What I'm trying to understand is if it's a Youtube problem or if there's something wrong in my code.
I've tried with many videos, the one in the code is just my last attempt.
I'm using Android SDK Version 15.

Comment: You can't load youtube video in a android video view. But you can use webview, load the embed code of the corresponding video url

Comment: The link is not getting played from a desktop version of VLC as well. You could take a look at [android-youtube-player](http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/) for an activity that plays Youtube videos and it is open source.

Comment: @Aerrow: Why can't I do it? I got my code following different tutorials on this. Anyway, I also tried to use a WebView with Youtube embed code, but the result was just an empty white or black rectangle (I don't know why it wasn't always white or always black).

Comment: @Rajesh: It seems a good solution, but I have some problems I hope I'll solve. Thank you again, I didn't know about this resource!

Comment: @Rajesh : I solved using android-youtube-player, if you write it as an answer, I'll check it as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting it as an answer as the OP solved it using this suggestion, so that it could be of help to anyone else looking for a similar solution.

There is an open source project that enables playing of YouTube videos from within a `VideoView`, and is called [android-youtube-player](http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/). There is a sample `Activity` also provided so that the component can be tested out.